# Replace null values of a pandas data frame with groupby mean value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, fillna

I have a data frame with below data:

[image: df]

I want to replace the null values of each country by its respective mean values.

For Eg,
I have calculated the mean values with following code:

```html
df2=df.groupby('country').mean()
```

[image: mean]

I have to replace the null values in df with corresponding mean value present in df2.
If the mean value is NaN, then keep Nan, else the value.

I have tried with below code but failed :
1.Output still has NaN values:

[image: Output still has NaN values]

2.

```html
df['retail'] = df['retail'].replace('',df.groupby('country').mean())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To replace nulls with the mean of the column you should do:

```
 df['transit_stations'] = df['transit_stations'].fillna(df2.groupby('country')['transit_stations'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: But the problem with the above code is, its not replacing the null values with its corresponding country's mean value.

My expectation is to replace null value of one dataframe with corresponding country's mean lookup value

Comment: I have corrected my answer above following your clarification

Comment: If you are not taking the mean from another DF, then change df2 to df